# Flutter commands stuck waiting for startup lock

Tags: flutter

I'm using macOS Catalina v10.15.5, and just installed flutter using git. But whenever I execute flutter commands (flutter doctor, flutter precache), I'm stuck at `Waiting for another flutter command to release the startup lock...`

Has been leaving it for >30min, still stuck at the error page.

List of solutions I've tried:

- `killall -9 dart` -> gets "No matching processes belonging to you were found FAIL: 1"
- Removing `<YOUR FLUTTER FOLDER>/bin/cache/lockfile` -> there is no lockfile
- delete the directory & restart PC & download again -> still the same error message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try remove flock check in _lock function in bin/internal/shared.sh like this

```
function _lock () {
  if hash shlock 2>/dev/null; then
    shlock -f "$1" -p $$
  else
    mkdir "$1" 2>/dev/null
  fi
}
```

For my case, my mac system had a flock enabled, but it was failing to acquire the lock.

Comment: thank you! I do realize I have flock, whereas the comment in shared.sh says flock is not supposed to work in macOS

Comment: Saved my life! Thank you

Comment: After hours of debugging and restarting my mac, this worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Try creating a new flutter project via File > Create new flutter project.
This will remove the lock.

Comment: didnt work for me.